# IE javascript location, window.open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window, location

I have a small problem. For some weird reason any attempt to change url via javascript, be it window.open, window.location, window.location.href, etc. doesnt move to the desired page, but adds it to end of the url. It doesnt even matter what IE version, from 6-8

E.g.

```
http://localhost/blabla/produkt/philips-fc-861501-animal-care/3639
```

ends in

```
http://localhost/blabla/produkt/philips-fc-861501-animal-care/added-by-javascript
```

I have no idea why this happens...

On this page

```
http://localhost/blabla/objednat-tovar?step=deal-detail
```

it works as intended.

Any help is appreciated...

EDIT:

Some code.

I am on

```
http://localhost/blabla/produkt/philips-fc-861501-animal-care/3639

// code
<a href="javascript:aaa(\'new_location\');" title="test">test</a>

function aaa(where) {
     window.location = where;
}
```

Ends in

```
http://localhost/blabla/produkt/philips-fc-861501-animal-care/new_location
```

Same thing happens with window.location.href, window.open and only in IEs

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: Added some code... it looks to me like it removes everything up to the first "/" and appends it

Comment: That is how relative URLs work. Nothing wrong here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve what every other browser does. Get http://localhost/blabla/new_location instead of what IE does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the browser tries to parse the [location as a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) and if it fails then, presumably, it does whatever it wants (IE seems to append the string to the current location).  For example:

```
window.location = 'about:blank'; // OK, since it's a valid pseudo-url.
window.location = 'foo'; // No effect, since this isn't a URL.
window.location = 'http://example.com/'; // OK, browse to that page.
window.location = 'bar'; // Depends on what the browser wants to do...
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `javascript:` here

```
<a href="#" onclick="aaa(\'new_location\');" title="test">test</a>

function aaa(where) {
     window.location = where;
}
```